# Can't bind to 'rows' since it isn't a known property of 'p-paginator' in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeNG with Angular . I have tried to use the paginator in conjunction with some cards and it worked perfectly. Now, I have re-created the project with exact same code. However, even after importing the "PaginatorModule" in the curretn module, I am getting

```
Can't bind to 'rows' since it isn't a known property of 'p-paginator'
```

Can you suggest a possible solution for this?

Here's the code.

```
<p-paginator [rows]="10" [totalRecords]="totalCount" (onPageChange)="paginate($event)"></p-paginator>
```

App Module:

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './service/interceptor/token.service';
import { SidebarModule } from 'primeng/sidebar';
import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, SidebarModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, ChartsModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot(), CardModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can u share your appmodule

Comment: @Çağrı Done adding.

Comment: Thanks. Then Error is what I expected :) U need to import module. For primeng u need to import every module u will use :) @joler-botol

Comment: I added the app.module because you wanted to see it. I do have PaginatorModule imported in the module I am using it in.

Comment: Can u create stackblitz example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the PaginatorModule:

```
import {PaginatorModule} from 'primeng/paginator';

...
imports: [
    BrowserModule, SidebarModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, ChartsModule, PaginatorModule
    OAuthModule.forRoot(), CardModule
  ],
...
```

Comment: No. I added the  app.module as another member wanted to see it.  Paginator is being used in another module. I have imported it there.

Comment: And does the other module also exports the PaginatorModule? Only importing it doesn't work

Comment: Yes. I have a module called SharedComponentsModule, which imports and exports PaginatorModule. SharedComponentsModule is, in turn, imported by another module where I want to use the Paginator.

Comment: Do you use the paginator in app.component?